# If only segmentation is enabled

Tags: operating-system, x86

beginners question:

- "If" paging is disabled and only segmentation is enabled (CR0.PE is set) then does that mean if a program is loaded in memory (RAM), its whole binary image is loaded and none of its "part" is swapped out, becoz a program is broken into fixed size chunks only when paging is enabled (which then can be swapped out). And if it's true this will reduce the number of processes that run in memory of a particular size of RAM, say 2 GB?

Answer (score 0):

Likely, but not necessarily.

It depends on the operating system...

You could write an operating system that uses a segment to map a part of the program into memory. When the program accesses memory outside the segment, you get a segmentation fault. As the segmentation fault is then passed to the operating system, it *could* swap in some data from disk and modify segmentation information, before returning control to the program.

However, this is probably difficult and expensive to do, and i do not know of any operating system that acts in this way.

As to the number of processes - you need to split the available memory into contiguous parts, one for each process. This is easy if processes do not grow; if they do, you need padding and may need to copy processes around, which is rather expensive...